# How to keep the pointer centered in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am writing some kind of a navigation program using Google Maps, and the issue is that when I change my location, I want the map to follow me and keep me in the center of the screen. 
Here's what I have for it so far.

```
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location lastKnownLocation) {
                try {
                    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(map.getMyLocation().getLatitude(),
                            map.getMyLocation().getLongitude()));
                    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(getZoomLevel());

                    map.moveCamera(center);
                    map.animateCamera(zoom);

                } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Now the problem is that it keeps following me, and I'm always on the screen while moving for example by car, but I'm not always in the center of the map.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onMyLocationChange(Location lastKnownLocation) {
        try {
              if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()),Constants.MAP_ZOOM));
              }
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
});
```